# AngularJS error: Unexpected request (No more requests expected)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In my AngularJS application, I'm having trouble figuring out how to unit test that the execution of a then promise changes a location.url. I have a function, **login**, that calls a service, **AuthenticationService**.  It returns the promise, and the execution of the then promise changes the location.url.

This is the controller **AuthCtrl**:

```
angular
  .module('bloc1App')
  .controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$location', 'AuthenticationService',
  function($scope, $http, $location, AuthenticationService) { 

   this.AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService;
   var self = this;

  $scope.login = function(username, password){
    self.AuthenticationService
      .login(username, password)
      .then(function(){
        $location.url('/tasks');
      });
  };
 }
]);
```

This is my attempt at the unit test:

```
    describe('Controller: AuthCtrl', function () {

      var scope,
          location,
          route,
          q,
          rootScope,
          AuthCtrl;

      beforeEach(module('bloc1App'));

      beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $location, $route, $q) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        location = $location;
        route = $route;

      AuthCtrl = $controller('AuthCtrl', {
         $scope: scope,
         $route: route,
         $location: location
      });

    }));

    it('login should redirect user to tasks view', function(){
      var deferred = q.defer();
      spyOn(AuthCtrl.AuthenticationService, 'login').andReturn(deferred.promise);
      spyOn(location, 'url');
      scope.login('foo', 'foo');
      deferred.resolve();
      scope.$apply();
      expect(location.url).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/tasks');
    });
   });
```

When I run this test, I get this error.  I get the same error if I use rootScope.$apply() instead:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET views/AuthView.html
No more request expected
```

When I take out scope.$apply(), I get this error:

```
Expected spy url to have been called with [ '/tasks' ] but it was never called.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  This is the first time that I'm unit testing a promise, and I'm probably conceptually misunderstanding how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're unit-testing with AngularJS, you're actually using mock services from [`ngMock`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ngMock) module instead of real services. In this case, your error probably comes form [`$httpBackend`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) mock, which has to be "primed" first, if you're expecting the tested units to use `$http` to send real requests. (I don't see your code using `$http` anywhere, so I'm guessing there's a part you're not showing here.)

Basically, you need to tell the `$httpBackend` mock that you're expecting a particular request using `$httpBackend.when` (or you can use `$httpBackend.expect`, if you want the mock to check that the request was really called) and what response should be returned.

So, your error has nothing to do with promises and everything to do with testing units that connect to server.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!  The service, AuthenticationService, makes http requests.  Because I'm testing the controller, I didn't think this would matter.  However, I took your suggestion and added the httpBackend mock using expect, and now the unit test works!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a moot point to be answering the question nearly two years after it has been asked, but the accepted answer is not quite right. The problem is that you are not properly mocking out `AuthenticationService`. You should completely mock out the functionality of the service, testing only *that* the service has been called from the controller, and save the `$httpBackend` stuff for testing the service itself. What you want to do is inject a fake `AuthenticationService` (as well as mock instantiations of Angular services such as `$q`, `$location`, and `$route`, if we're following best practices) into the `beforeEach`, and then declare it in the `$controller` definition. You can also include your spies in the `beforeEach` block.

```
describe('AuthCtrl', function(){

  var $q;
  var $location;
  var $controller;
  var AuthenticationService;
  var $route;
  var deferred;

  beforeEach(inject(function( _$controller_, $rootScope, _AuthenticationService_, _$q_, _$location_, _$route_){

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    AuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;
    $location = _$location_;
    $route = _$route_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $q = _$q_;
    deferred = $q.defer();

    spyOn(AuthenticationService, 'login').andReturnValue(deferred.promise);
    spyOn($location, 'url');

    AuthCtrl = $controller('AuthCtrl', {
      scope: scope,
      AuthenticationService: AuthenticationService,
      $route: $route,
      $location: $location
    };

  }));

  it('should redirect the user on login', function(){
      deferred.resolve();
      scope.$apply();
      expect($location.url).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/tasks');
  }); 
});
```

Note that it's important to make your controller definition the last item in the `beforeEach` block if you are defining your variables this way, or else the mocks won't be properly instantiated and the service methods will actually be called, regardless of spies.